# Add PHP Dynamic Methods in IDE Autocomplete

Tags: php, autocomplete, ide

I need to make some dynamic methods in my PHP class.

Using this class:

```php
class SampleClassWithDynamicMethod
{
    public function __call($methodName, $values)
    {
        if(!method_exists($this, $methodName)){
            // Do something...
            return "You called $methodName!";
        }
    }

$sample = new SampleClassWithDynamicMethod();
echo $sample->test(); 
// You called test!

echo $sample->anotherTest();
// You called anotherTest!

echo $sample->moreTest(); 
// You called moreTest!
```

It works well. But how can I let the IDE know this class has these dynamic methods with these names: `test()`, `anotherTest()` and `moreTest()`?

Comment: If you have specific methods, why would you not want to actually declare them in your class.  Even if they just pass through to a main stub, it would be clearer (IMHO).

Comment: @NigelRen I've more than 25 methods which have a little different. I can add all of these manually but i think it make my code noisy, If I thought right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP DocBlocks. These are supported by major PHP IDEs.

Specifically, the `@method` annotation. Check the [docs](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html).

Using the example from the docs:

```
/**
  * @method string getString()
  * @method void setInteger(integer $integer)
  * @method setString(integer $integer)
  * @method static string staticGetter()
  */
 class Child extends Parent
 {
     // <...>
 }
```

This would declare that could could do any of the following, which would be recognized by the IDE and offered for auto-completion (obviously, assuming the methods have been implemented in some way):

```
$child = new Child();
$child->setInteger(10);
$child->setString(2);
echo $child->getString();
// 2

$string = Child::staticGetter();
```